# How to check iOS Version is iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

I want to check iOS Version in iOS.

Because i have some of codes only for iOS 6.

So how can i?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check this GitHub Gist
https://gist.github.com/998472

You can add the code or include it in your ...-Prefix.pch file so you can use it wherever you need it.

---

EDIT

I'm leaving an example of how you can use the code from Gist so people can check if it's useful for their case. This can also be found over the Gist.

```
/*
 *  Usage
 */ 

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"4.0")) {
    ...
}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"3.1.1")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: While I love the code you have over in the gist (as I commented there), it'd be even better if you could include an example of it in this answer.

Comment: It's not my gist and I won't include the code here as the gist is made to be improved over time and this answer is stale in time. However I'm going to leave an example of how to use it so people can see if it's useful for their case. Thanks for caring :)

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

*Update:*

```
NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    // iOS-7 code[current] or greater
} else if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] == 6) {
    // iOS-6 code
} else if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] > 2) {
    // iOS-3,4,5 code
} else {
    // iOS-1,2... code: incompatibility warnings, legacy-handlers, etc..  
}
```

*Previous code:*

```
NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] == 6) {
    // iOS-6 code
} else {
    // iOS-5, iOS-4... code     
}
```

To specifically check for a subversion of IOS use

```
float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (sysVer > 6.01) {
    // iOS-6.01+ code
} else {
    // prior iOS versions
}
```

Comment: If iOS Version is 6.0.1 and above 6, your code is still ok?

Comment: yes. Only the first index is checked

Comment: This fails to future-proof against iOS 7 and above. Should be `if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 6)`

Comment: @c.cam108 Your comment is duly noted and the code updated.

Comment: @LoSauer thanks - downvote duly rescinded. Thanks for coming back to update this!

Comment: As a side note [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] is very slow, so best to cache the result if you need switched code in a loop or in lots of places.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the iOS version as a string using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```