# Best Way to check for iOS 7 or earlier?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I need to reconfigure some UI based on the iOS version I am running against, so I need a good way of checking the iOS version. For the time being I am doing this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString: @"7.0"]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I'd prefer not to hard code these string comparisons and make decisions based on that. Are there any better ways of doing this?

Comment: That will break if iOS 7.1 comes out. But you're on the right track.Split the string up and compare the major version only, if you care about iOS7 in general.

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561599/how-to-check-ios-version-is-ios-6/12561661#12561661

Comment: this looks the most stable

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I always keep those in my Constants.h file:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES) 
#define IS_OS_5_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0)
#define IS_OS_6_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
#define IS_OS_7_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
#define IS_OS_9_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0)
```

Although I'll always prefer the above macros, for the completion of the accepted answer, here is the apple approved way:

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    // do stuff for iOS 7 and newer

}
else {

    // do stuff for older versions than iOS 7
}
```

Comment: cool man, nice utility belt.

Comment: side effect of this is [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] will be called each time you use the macro.  The systemVersion method has historically been surprisingly slow, so if you have recursion of any description cache the result value.

Comment: This is really not a good approach, for a number of reasons. For specifics, please see the comments on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3341214/214149).

Comment: Why i prefer my answer: 1. I only care about big releases 5,6,7 so float is just fine. 2. So far this raw floating point comparison never failed me. Sometimes convenience will win in battle against "you must be aware of that edge case that will never happen".

Comment: Nice collection! Added :)

Comment: If you want to differentiate between iOS7 and iOS8, keep in mind that you should check firstly for iOS8 and later, then for iOS7...iOS6... and so on

Comment: I don't like the first approach because you conflate macros and conditional compilation with a runtime check for the system version, confusing to me, I would have just made a static method or something like that

Comment: Do not use these macros. There are proper ways to check APIs at runtime.

Answer (score 117):

```
if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

    // do stuff for iOS 7 and newer

}
else {

    // do stuff for older versions than iOS 7
}
```

Comment: +1 I have never seen this before.

Comment: For what it's worth, this was Apple's suggestion at the 2013 Tech Talk in the adopting iOS 7 session - although they wrapped `NSFoundationVersionNumber` in a call to `floor()`.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a 6.2.x which would make the check invalid?

Comment: Nope--that wouldn't invalidate the check. Have a look at NSObjCRuntime.h.

Comment: It's also in print in the iOS 7 Transition Guide: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html). See "Loading Resources Conditionally."

Comment: Currently the last version to check is still iOS7: #define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 1047.25