# Custom Nav Bar, Button-compatibility issues with iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

The app I'm working on has a customized nav bar.  In my AppDelegate.m I have done the following:

- setBackgroundImage has replaced the default color of the Nav Bar with one of my own .png images;
- setTitleTextAttributes: has been set to white;
- setTintColor: has been set to white;

  ```
  - (void)customizeUserInterface {
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  }
  ```

Everything looks just fine in iOS 7, but on devices that run iOS 6 the Nav Bar buttons are white on white, because while the tint color changes the text of the button in iOS 7 (because that's all buttons are in iOS 7 - text), in iOS 6 setting tint color adjusts the background of the button, and the text remains white.  So in iOS 6, the nav bar buttons are white with white text.

I rather like how my tables look in iOS 7, and would rather not change it just because backwards compatibility with iOS 6 is not cooperating.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue.  Is there a way to programmatically change either the background color of the Nav Bar round rec buttons or just the text within the round rec buttons - all while not changing the appearance in iOS 7?

Or is there are way to set these changes conditionally?  In other words, can I programmatically set the custom Nav Bar to appear only for devices with iOS 7+, and use the default for all iOS versions before that?

Or is there something else clever out there that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks!

Comment: Inside the customizeUserInterface method, I would recommend a big if/else if statement that tests the version of the device. If it is iOS 7, do this, but if it iOS 6, do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey that's really possible to control your stuff programmatically. You have your ways to do it in ios7 & definitely you have done it for ios6.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992983/1307844) to check version.

Now you can do things conditionally.

Hope that helps.