# Top half of UINavigationBar on iOS6 not responding to taps

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm working on an iPhone app and have the strangest issue.

On iOS 6, buttons on the navigation bar are completely ignoring taps in the top half. Have a look at the image below, I have roughly selected tap areas of my navbar buttons:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/izs6ic5jlubm1yk/navtap_problem.png

Here's some, potentially useful, information:

- the app supports iOS 6 and 7
- the app is not using autolayout (working with deltas instead)
- this issue is present only on iOS 6, it's working fine on iOS 7
- the issue is present in all views across the app (that have a navigation bar on top)
- the issue present in both navigation bars that are manually added in IB as well as in navigation bars that are coming from the UINavigationController
- the problem is not present if I directly start the app from one of affected view controllers
- the problem is present when I start the app through my empty InitialViewController and load another VC

I'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) and loading the real VC (that users will see) from the InitialViewController like this:

```
self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchSplitViewNavigationController"];
[self resetTopView];
```

It looks like something invisible is covering the top half of the navigation screen. I checked the contents of self.view.subviews, but didn't see anything there.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Or what else could I check?

Comment: Might be something to do with the transparency of iOS7. Are e.g the boxes to extend under edges (top and bottom) ticked in your view controller properties section ?

Comment: It very likely has something to do with your use of deltas. My guess is that the top part of your topViewController's view is outside the frame of it's parent view.

Comment: Ohnomycoco: Yes, both "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars" are selected. Unselecting them doesn't make a difference. Andy: I'm only setting -20 to delta Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution (not the cause though). [This awesome library](https://github.com/lukaswelte/DCIntrospect-ARC) helped me a lot to identify the problem.

There was actually a transparent UIView sitting on top of my navigation bars. It was located at 0,20 and had a height of 20 points.

That view is not in the `self.view.subviews` array, but doing `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myNavigationBar]` seems to do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If you are including any element programmatically, then that element isn't using the deltas you are including through the storyboard.
For these elements you must test for the iOS version you're in and adjust the delta in code.

Check this: [Best Way to check for iOS 7 or earlier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992766/best-way-to-check-for-ios-7-or-earlier) for help on the version checking.