# How can I modify PKRevealController slide-out menus to deal with iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

I have an application using [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) which implements a slide-out menu similar to the ones in the popular Facebook and GMAIL apps on iOS. The app is built in XCode 5, and runs on iOS 6 and iOS 7.  I need to figure out how to have it work sanely in both places, so a simple .XIB hack that makes it look okay in iOS 7 but makes it look worse in iOS 6 is not okay.

The code works great for iOS 6, where the status bar is opaque and the top view is not alpha-blended with the status bar.

However, on iOS 7, just for example, I have created this view in my .xib file, here is how it appears running in ioS 6 simulator, shown here with the slide out menu opened:

[image]

The same .xib file running on ios 7, when the slide-out menu open, the top of the slide out menu's .xib content is now under the status bar, as Apple said it would be in their ios 7 transition guide:

[image]

The class I need to modify in PKRevealController is probably the presenting view controller that is creating and presenting the contained view, the contained view is called `PKRevealControllerContainerView`, I think.  I think I probably need to create
some kind of view hierarchy like this:

```
   [  Outermost View container 
        [ some kind of blob to occupy the header area ]
        [ the client view I want to appear the way it did in iOS 6]
   ]
```

I've been reading around, and there may be much simpler approaches, but I don't quite understand them, approaches like adding properties to my info.plist, like `View controller-based status bar appearance` = `YES`.  I tried that it did not have the desired effect.

How do I go about fixing this? I have read the [Fine Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/) published by Apple and it has not provided code, only general guidance like this page on the [status bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html).

It's easy to replicate this problem, just clone the git repo `https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController`, build and run.

The code that brings up the pop-up view looks like this:

```
- (void)addLeftViewControllerToHierarchy
{
    if (self.leftViewController != nil && ![self.childViewControllers containsObject:self.leftViewController])
    {
        [self addChildViewController:self.leftViewController];
        self.leftViewContainer.viewController = self.leftViewController;

        if (self.leftViewContainer == nil)
        {
            self.leftViewContainer = [[PKRevealControllerContainerView alloc] initForController:self.leftViewController shadow:NO];
            self.leftViewContainer.autoresizingMask = [self autoresizingMaskForLeftViewContainer];
        }

        self.leftViewContainer.frame = [self leftViewFrame];
        [self.view insertSubview:self.leftViewContainer belowSubview:self.frontViewContainer];
        [self.leftViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

The above is invoked by PKRevealController.m, like this:

```
- (void)showLeftViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
                            completion:(PKDefaultCompletionHandler)completion
{
    __weak PKRevealController *weakSelf = self;

    void (^showLeftViewBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [weakSelf removeRightViewControllerFromHierarchy];
        [weakSelf addLeftViewControllerToHierarchy];  // HELLO LEFT Slide-out menu.

        ....
```

Is there a better approach than my idea? Did Apple provide some way to make this easy or does trying to support iOS 6 and iOS 7 in a single codebase leave me doing hacks like the above I'm considering?

Here, for instance, is a really ugly hack where I don't bother placing any view underneath the apple system status bar, leaving a black bar at the top, which is no good, but it shows I'm modifying the right area in the code, at least:

```
- (void)addLeftViewControllerToHierarchy
{
    CGRect   lvFrame;

    if (self.leftViewController != nil && ![self.childViewControllers containsObject:self.leftViewController])
    {
        [self addChildViewController:self.leftViewController];
        self.leftViewContainer.viewController = self.leftViewController;

        if (self.leftViewContainer == nil)
        {
            self.leftViewContainer = [[PKRevealControllerContainerView alloc] initForController:self.leftViewController shadow:NO];
            self.leftViewContainer.autoresizingMask = [self autoresizingMaskForLeftViewContainer];
        }

        lvFrame = [self leftViewFrame];
        lvFrame.origin.y += 20; // ugly hack demo code only! don't really do it this badly!
        lvFrame.size.height -= 20;
        self.leftViewContainer.frame = lvFrame;
        [self.view insertSubview:self.leftViewContainer belowSubview:self.frontViewContainer];
        [self.leftViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

The above hack is almost enough, if I also add this to `UIViewController+PKRevealController.m`:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
}
```

The above code, when added, causes the following hint/warning:

`Category is implementing a method that will also be implemented by its primary class.`

I'm including the above notes to show what I've tried, and I welcome some idea of how the real experts are doing this.

My own modified copy of the PKRevealController code, including the hack above, in a slightly improved form, is found here:  `https://github.com/wpostma/PKRevealController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with PKRevealController as well. While I'm still looking for better solutions I will share what I came up with until now.

My two problems were:

1. Status bar style was always the same and I wanted a different style for the front view and the menu;
2. The menu view top cell (it's a table view controller) showed up behind the status bar.

### 1. Dynamic status bar style

First I had my own PKRevealController subclass where I was having a custom initialiser and some custom methods to load new view controllers into the front view navigation view controller. But that's not relevant for now.

I used this subclass to implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` as follows so that the reveal controller can provide the right style for each state:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    switch (self.state) {
        case PKRevealControllerFocusesLeftViewController:
            return [self.leftViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
            break;
        case PKRevealControllerFocusesRightViewController:
            return [self.rightViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
            break;
        case PKRevealControllerFocusesFrontViewController:
            return [self.frontViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
            break;
        case PKRevealControllerFocusesLeftViewControllerInPresentationMode:
            return [self.leftViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
            break;
        case PKRevealControllerFocusesRightViewControllerInPresentationMode:
            return [self.rightViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
            break;

        default:
            return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
            break;
    }
}
```

This alone doesn't work however. You still have to say that the status bar style needs to change with `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`. As Apple says this should be called from inside an animation loop and you can find one in PKRevealController's `setFrontViewFrameLinearly` method. This is how it looks after I've modified it:

```
- (void)setFrontViewFrameLinearly:(CGRect)frame
                         animated:(BOOL)animated
                         duration:(CGFloat)duration
                          options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                       completion:(PKDefaultCompletionHandler)completion
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0f options:options animations:^
    {
        self.frontViewContainer.frame = frame;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
            [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        }
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        safelyExecuteCompletionBlockOnMainThread(completion, finished);
    }];
}
```

If you try it out at this point the styles will be mixed up. You can quickly conclude that by the time `preferredStatusBarStyle` is called the reveal controller state is still not changed. For that go to every method that sets the state, e.g. `enterPresentationModeForRightViewControllerAnimated` and set the state before it calls any change to the frame (the one is going to trigger the animation loop). I did it in 5 different places.

### 2. Left/Right menu with inset

For this one I have to say I used a workaround: I've just set a header view on the table view (`tableHeaderView` property).

Put this in `viewDidLoad` of your UITableViewController:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 20.f)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Don't forget to add some condition so it doesn't get executed in iOS 6. Use [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561599/how-to-check-ios-version-is-ios-6/12561703#12561703) to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need iOS 5- support, you could use autolayout and align topmost views to `topLayoutGuide`.

[image: iOS6]
[image: iOS7]

So, for example, if your left view controller is a UIViewController with a UITableView in it, you could snap UITableView's top edge to the topLayoutGuide. 
You can do it in **(1)** IB (storyboard) or **(2)** from code.

I personally prefer the **first approach**, as far as it removes the need of unnecessary code. You just open your storyboard and snap your table view's top edge to topLayoutGuide. In iOS 7 you'll end up with topLayoutGuide constraint, in iOS6 topLayoutGuide constraint is converted to a common to-container-view constant.
 

[image: IB way]


If you use **second approach**, you'll have to make sure you don't use topLayoutGuide in iOS6, something like this:

```
// assume you'r in your UIViewController subclass
if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) 
{
    // topLayoutGuide is not supported, probably iOS6
    // add constraints to snap tableview's top edge to superview's top edge
}
else
{
    // cool, topLayoutGuide is supported, probably iOS7
    // add constraints to snap tableview's top edge to topLayoutGuide
}
```