# Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

```
#define A7VERSION() ({[[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];})

#define IS_OS_7 A7VERSION()>=7
```

The above declaration seems to compile well.

But as soon as I add it a .m file I get the following exception  "invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression". I am not able to understand where I could be wrong

```
@implementation AppViewController
#if IS_OS_7
….
#else
….  
#endif
@end
```

Comment: Due to the dynamic nature of Objective-C, the value of method calls cannot be determined at compile time, meaning that a runtime check is all that you can do.  A good list of runtime checks is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION. Its related to preprocessor . Nor does my question title specify its a version check code.I was expecting it to work at runtime which was wrong and corrected by @bbum

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with iOS 7.

Your `#define` does not lead to something that can be resolved at compile time.  An `#ifdef` only works if the conditional is something that can be determined at compile time.    It cannot be used to change behavior at runtime based on the environment an app is running on.

Comment: its not #ifdef. it is #if condition

Comment: @weber67 doesn't matter.  It is still a compile time test that cannot generate dynamic behavior at runtime.