# Macro in Objective-C calling isEqualToString: produces error about invalid token

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I'm trying to define a macro like this:

```
#define SOME_DEF [[TTys getString] isEqualToString:ANOTHER_STRING]
```

and then doing the following:

```
#if SOME_DEF
...
#endif
```

- `[TTys getString]` returns an NSString
- `ANOTHER_STRING` is defined earlier as `#define ANOTHER_STRING "hello"`

I get the following error on the `#if SOME_DEF` line:

> Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481396/invalid-token-at-start-of-a-preprocessor-expression-xcode) this might be caused by something that can't be resolved at compile time, but I have everything defined. My suspect is 
the `isEqualToString` method, but I don't know of another way to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this as a macro and not just a function? I can tell you from experience it's best to avoid macros when possible.

Comment: Are you expecting to evaluate the `isEqualToString:` call during the preprocessor stage?

Answer (score 2):

When you write `#if SOME_DEF` the preprocessor resolves it into:

```
#if [[TTys getString] isEqualToString:ANOTHER_STRING]
```

This is not a valid condition for the `#if` preprocessor directive:

> The ‘#if’ directive allows you to test the value of an arithmetic
>   expression, rather than the mere existence of one macro. Its syntax is
>
> ```
>  #if expression
>
>  controlled text
>
>  #endif /* expression */
> ```
>
> *expression* is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent restrictions. It may contain
>
> - Integer constants.
> - Character constants, which are interpreted as they
>     would be in normal code.
> - Arithmetic operators for addition,
>     subtraction, multiplication, division, bitwise operations, shifts,
>     comparisons, and logical operations (&& and ||). The latter two obey
>     the usual short-circuiting rules of standard C.
> - Macros. All macros in
>     the expression are expanded before actual computation of the
>     expression's value begins.
> - Uses of the defined operator, which lets
>     you check whether macros are defined in the middle of an ‘#if’.
> - Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the
>     number zero. This allows you to write #if MACRO instead of #ifdef
>     MACRO, if you know that MACRO, when defined, will always have a
>     nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call
>     parentheses are also treated as zero.

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html).

What you can do instead is using a runtime-evaluated regular if-statement:

```
if(SOME_DEF) {
    ...
}
```