# Can I set two different xib for the same UIVIewController for iOS6 and iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

Can I set two different xibs for iOS6 and iOS7?

I can't make the same changes to the same xib file for both iOS, and I can't set everything in the code.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` as stated in this question's accepted answer: [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Get the version and conditionally load the correct XIB accordingly.

Comment: And what about those UIViewControllers that do not explicitly load the xib filename in the code but are just linked to the xib file using interface builder? This is actually how I load xib files, I haven't written any code for it.

Comment: one way may be having two different classes and two different view controllers designed, a polymorphic design with all the common parts inheriting from a base view controller, which shouldn't be much work.
another option, if you are using storyboards, may be having two different segues and conditionally calling one of them depending on the version.

Comment: All right, one last question: isn't there a way to specify in the xib file to which iOS it belongs to? So it won't be loaded with one iOS or the other?

Comment: as far as I know, there is no such way. the only difference I know for specifying different devices is the distinction between iphone(ipod) and ipad, and that's also with storyboards too, not xibs.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested Apple method to check the version on iOS is this one, it is also reported in the ios7 transitioning guide:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)