# System Version check show warning macro in iOS

Tags: ios, macros

I need to check the system iOS Version in my App.

my deployment target is iOS 5.

However when i checked with following codes , the warning message is appearing.

```
*Warning Messages : System_version_less_than macro redefiend*
```

and the codes is :

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest & easiest answer here is to put this line:

```
#undef SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN
```

before your "`#define`" lines.

Then again, doing a bit more research into [(the massively upvoted answer) where these "`#define`" lines came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version/5337804#5337804), you may be #defining them in the wrong way.  Are you putting them in a "`.h`" file that you are *importing*, or how else are you including or defining them?

Comment: yes bro . got it. thanks a lot. need to wait 10 minute to tick answers. :D