# Disable delegate methods depending on iOS version

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uipickerview

I'm using some `UIPickerView` delegate methods only for the brand-new-Ive-modified iOS under NDA, e.g.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

I don't want to implement them for `iOS6,` to preserve default `iOS` behavior, so a condition inside the method won't work. How to do it?

Comment: This may be answered by the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version

Comment: If the delegate method is only declared for a particular version of iOS or later, it will only get called in those versions only. You'd have to deal with that and find another way.

Comment: It is declared in previous versions of iOS, so it is called

Comment: You could try swizzling method implementations or adding a mehtod implementation only for a certain OS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your delegate, override `respondsToSelector:` and return `NO` in case of old OS:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    if (selector == @selector(pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:))
        return MyFunctionThatChecksIosVersionIsMinimum7();
    return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}
```

So you're implementing the delegate method normally. When the picker view is asking your delegate if it understands the message you're simply lying to it.