# UIBarButtonItem setTintColor doesn't work on iOS7

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor

In iOS6, I used this code to make my UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem* validate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"MyTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionValidate)];
    [validate setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = validate;
```

It works fine in iOS6 but in iOS7, the color of the button changes only when you push it.. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

In iOS7 you if you need to change the `navigationBar` buttons color, you must set `tintColor` for the `navgationBar` not the for specific `barButton` any more.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Edit: this works in iOS7, you need to do the check:

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion >= 7.0)
{
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor]
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change the entire bar, only the button. I use the IOS6 interface even if the user is in IOS 7.

Comment: It changes the bar buttons NOT the bar itself.

Comment: What if you only want to change one of the buttons and not all the buttons?

Comment: @stevex Then you need to fake this button by using a custom view.

Comment: I highly recommend not comparing versions with a float - that will not compare minor versions properly (ie 7.11 vs 7.2), and it will clobber anything after the minor version number (7.1.1). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version) for some options.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get @Chris's method to work (iOS 8 like @Adama says).

My use case is that I want to set all `UIToolbar` & `UINavigationBar` buttons to a default colour. So using the `UIAppearance` API:

`UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Normal)`