# iOS UIBarButtonItem only change after first press

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Im having issue where i just using a simple UIBarButton and named it "Send" and white tint color using Storyboard

In viewdidload, i use this code to change the tint color to red, but it stay to white color, and only change to red after i press it 1 time and also, it become a bit smaller @-@ , cant figure out whats the problem here, i dont have any code before that can change the button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_sendEPinButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardOnScreen:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardOffScreen:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];

    if (carrier.isoCountryCode.length == 0) {
        self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
//        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } else {
        countryCodeString = carrier.isoCountryCode;
    }
    _contactTextfield.delegate = self;

    [_contactTextfield setTintColor:colorFromRGB(67, 160, 48)];
}
```

In .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sendEPinButton;
```

Before press
[image]

After Press
[image]

Comment: Could you include your `viewDidLoad` code?

Comment: can you try placing that code in viewdidappear ?

Comment: show us the screenshot

Comment: Im not sure why but place in viewdidappear fix it o_o thanks...u can make it an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131481/uibarbuttonitem-settintcolor-doesnt-work-on-ios7

Comment: The other question doesnt really got the answer at all...still not sure why cant put it in viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the code in ViewDidAppear method and see. Sometimes the outlets will not load properly in view did load method.

Answer (score 0):

you should write these line in viewdidload or where you created your UIBarButtonItem..

```
[_sendEPinButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Sorry, as i said, i really don't have any code that change the UIBarButtonItem before that line, the only thing that i did is create the button in storyboard and set tint to white and name it Send, thats all