# iOS target app for both iOS 6 and iOS 7 with ECSlidingViewController component

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, compatibility

I am using `ECSlidingViewController` for "hamburger" menu. I am using SDK 7.0 but I changed deployment target to iOS 6.1 and now I am trying my app with older iOS then 7. The problem is with `setEdgesForExtendedLayout`. There is older `ECSlidingViewController` for older system versions. So my question is how can I change to use old version for iOS 6.1 and older and newer version for iOS 7.0 and newer. I include files from both `ECSlidingViewController` projects (not by cocoapods but if it is need then it's not problem to change it). I guess I need check for OS version and then change imports but I am not sure if it is enough and what's best name convention for both project. I guess they should be in different folders (like ECSlidingViewController and ECSlidingViewControllerOld) but class should be same name, is it right?

**Edit:** Example of code with `edgesForExtendedLayout`:

```
- (CGRect)underLeftViewCalculatedFrameForTopViewPosition:(ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition)position {
    CGRect frameFromDelegate = [self frameFromDelegateForViewController:self.underLeftViewController
                                                        topViewPosition:position];
    if (!CGRectIsInfinite(frameFromDelegate)) return frameFromDelegate;

    CGRect containerViewFrame = self.view.bounds;

    if (!(self.underLeftViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & UIRectEdgeTop)) {
        CGFloat topLayoutGuideLength    = [self.topLayoutGuide length];
        containerViewFrame.origin.y     = topLayoutGuideLength;
        containerViewFrame.size.height -= topLayoutGuideLength;
    }

    if (!(self.underLeftViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & UIRectEdgeBottom)) {
        CGFloat bottomLayoutGuideLength = [self.bottomLayoutGuide length];
        containerViewFrame.size.height -= bottomLayoutGuideLength;
    }

    if (!(self.underLeftViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout & UIRectEdgeRight)) {
        containerViewFrame.size.width = self.anchorRightRevealAmount;
    }

    return containerViewFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a fan of including duplicate versions of libraries, as this creates a big problem with naming, and a lot of work to refactor all old classes to have some `*-OLD` suffix. Since you have access to the source, you can modify the newer version like so:

```
if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
{
    [vc setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];

    //Any other iOS7-specific code.
}
```

Comment: Modified code could be better way then adding duplicate component but what can I do with code which I added to my question?

Comment: @Bibo I am not sure 100% what this method does, but since on iOS, things are quite static (view controller is always under the same coordinates, you can fake the result with a hardcoded value for iOS6.1 and below.

Answer (score 0):

First, the easiest way to do it will be have the most recent version of component that support the lowest deployment target.

But if you really want to have different version for each `iOS`, I don't know better solution, than just rename all classes from, for example, older version (because there was only two classes) and manage creation of this controller programmatically, because there's no way to set different class for different `iOS` version in `xib`'s or `storyboard`'s. You need to wrap each and every call of this component with `iOS` version check ( [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version) ).

Imports and variables you can leave for each version of component without check.

The trick you mentioned failed in this case, because it works good for different architecture, because binaries for different architectures will be included in final app and that's named `fat binary`, but there's the same architecture for `iOS6` and `iOS7` ( only one new in `iOS7` - `arm64`). So you can't wrap only `include`s with preprocessor macros and get `fat binary` with different code for each iOS version.

I hope you've understood something from my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only thing preventing you from using the new version with iOS 6 is the lack of `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`, which if available would just return lengths of zero anyway.

Why not "backport" those methods in your controller?

```
- (id<UILayoutSupport>)topLayoutGuide
{
    CustomLayoutGuide * guide = [CustomLayoutGuide new];
    guide.length = SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? super.topLayoutGuide.length : 0.0;
    return guide;
}
```

And the helper class

```
@interface CustomLayoutGuide : NSObject <UILayoutSupport>

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat length;

@end

@implementation CustomLayoutGuide

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest thing to do (and probably the best though) is to take the current ECSlidingViewController and integrate part of the old when `edgesForExtendedLayout` is not available (e.g. `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) { /*...*/}` ). This should be pretty easy and fast to do since the old [ECSlidingViewController just consists of two files](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/tree/1.x/ECSlidingViewController/Vendor/ECSlidingViewController) and these files are also present in the new ECSlidingViewController. 
You could make your life even easier when doing this by using a diff tool to be sure of what you should add.