# iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1 issues with UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar, tint

I have recently updated Xcode to 5.1 and now have issues with the tab bar. In iOS 7 and Xcode 5.0 i used this code:

```
// Graph tab icon
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *graphTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *noRenderGraph = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"graph"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [graphTabIcon setImage:noRenderGraph];
    [graphTabIcon setTitle:@"Graph"];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Friends tab icon
    UITabBarItem *friendsTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UIImage *noRenderFriends = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"group"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [friendsTabIcon setImage:noRenderFriends];
    [friendsTabIcon setTitle:@"Friends"];
    // Settings tab icon
    UITabBarItem *settingsTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UIImage *noRenderSettings = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [settingsTabIcon setImage:noRenderSettings];
    [settingsTabIcon setTitle:@"Settings"];
    // Info tab icon
    UITabBarItem *infoTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UIImage *noRenderinfo = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"info"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [infoTabIcon setImage:noRenderinfo];
    [infoTabIcon setTitle:@"Info"];
```

and the result was this :

[image]

But now with 7.1 and Xcode 5.1 I get this :
[image]

I also tried this code :

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and that looked great on iOS 7.1, but on 7 ended up being a slight brown color.

So how can I make it so it works on both?

Comment: Why not check if 7.1 and use the code that works there? iOS7.0 has had many issues with the tab bar, and some of these are fixed in 7.1. You can also decide not to add specific support for 7.1, and ask users to upgrade if they see visual anomalies.

Comment: That would work, but it game me an idea. Do you know how you would tell if device iOS iOS 7.1 or 7?

Comment: Check out this answer for a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/983912

Comment: This worked, i wish i could give you your deserved rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Leo Natan's comments I did this :

### Edit

I ended up just adding both code snippets together and it works how I want it to

## App delegate

```
{
    // iOS 7 method
    // Graph tab icon
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *graphTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImage *noRenderGraph = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"graph"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [graphTabIcon setImage:noRenderGraph];
    [graphTabIcon setTitle:@"Graph"];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Friends tab icon
    UITabBarItem *friendsTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UIImage *noRenderFriends = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"group"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [friendsTabIcon setImage:noRenderFriends];
    [friendsTabIcon setTitle:@"Friends"];
    // Settings tab icon
    UITabBarItem *settingsTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UIImage *noRenderSettings = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [settingsTabIcon setImage:noRenderSettings];
    [settingsTabIcon setTitle:@"Settings"];
    // Info tab icon
    UITabBarItem *infoTabIcon = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UIImage *noRenderinfo = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"info"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [infoTabIcon setImage:noRenderinfo];
    [infoTabIcon setTitle:@"Info"];

    // iOS 7.1 method
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Comment: Make sure to flag as answered.

Comment: Have to wait for 2 days :(