# Semantic Issue - implicit declaration of function

Tags: ios, appirater

I am using Appirater (https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) to enable app ratings in my xcode project. Everything builds OK when using 'iOS Simulator' but when I use the 'iOS device' target to archive my project I get 2 build errors:

Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO' is invalid in C99

Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN' is invalid in C99

The relevant lines of code are in the Appirater.m file:

```
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") && SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.1")) {
        reviewURL = [templateReviewURLiOS7 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _appId]];
    }
```

I found a set of macros that are very similar to these in  [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version/5337804#5337804)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Add these lines from your link to your .pch file. Clean and build. It should go away.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

More info: since the preprocessor cannot find them to do a find and replace for these macros, they pass through to the compiler where they look like C functions. The compiler cannot find them and gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Please pull again from the repo. This should be working. Sorry about that.

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**
This is my fault. I accepted a new change with these macro calls into the Appirater repo without building/testing. I'm removing the offending macros now and will push a fix within the hour.