# Checking iOS version through preprocessor

Tags: objective-c, ios8

This is how i am checking if its iOS 8 and opening the settings app

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
#endif
```

question is if user gets iOS 8.1 in future, will this code work? I need to make sure if user has iOS8.0 or greater.

I have tested this, it works fine with iOS8

Thanks

Comment: Why is the preprocessor required? This isn't clear based only on your example. If its not, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis- Xcode wont even compile if i don't add preprocessor. Code that i have for opening settings app only works if you have base SDK 8.0 but i need to support 7.0 as well

Comment: My bad, my comment wasn't clear. My point was: why do you say you want to check the version *using the preprocessor* (as opposed to checking the version *at runtime*)?

Comment: @Paragon You only need to use a preprocessor directive if you need to build the code with both Xcode 6 (Base SDK of iOS 8) and Xcode 5 (Base SDK of iOS 7). If you use Xcode 6 and have a Base SDK of iOS 8 (or latest) and a Deployment Target of iOS 7, then you can support both versions of iOS with NO preprocessor directives. You would use a runtime check instead.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, but some people are still using Xcode 5 so i want to support both

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis because of Xcode 5

Comment: @Paragon Then you need both - a compiler directive and a runtime check. The compiler directive will protect users of Xcode 5 and the runtime check will ensure the app works properly on iOS 7 devices when built with Xcode 6.

Comment: But here is the problem, if i check for iOS version, if its iOS8 and above show 'settings button' and runtime check for code to open settings app, then if i build the app with Xcode 5 and user has iOS8 then it will show settings button but it will not do anything because Xcode 5 didn't even compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This preprocessor will always work in higher versions. In iOS 8.1 a new is defined: __IPHONE_8_1

You can see that __IPHONE_2_0 is defined up to __IPHONE_7_1 and __IPHONE_8_0, so the defined values are always kept in future versions.

Comment: but i am not checking if iOS8 or higher, its just saying iOS 8

Comment: `__IPHONE_8_0` will still be defined in Availability.h when Apple rolls out iOS 8.1, so your code will continue to work.

Comment: @Paragon I edited my post to explain this better, but as you can see all versions are defined and kept when future versions roll out.

Comment: @HannesSverrisson Thanks, just wanted to make sure that this condition will be true even if user has __IPHONE_8_1.