# Why isn't this device token being printed to the NSLog?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to print a device token to the Debugger Window. When building and running the app on a test device, the app receives a `Would Like to Send You Push Notifications` alert, but the NSLog doesn't print the device token.

```
//REGISTER FOR THE NOTIFICATIONS TYPES
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

//-- Set Notification
if (@available(iOS 8, *)) {
  // iOS 8 Notifications: Registering for notifications and types
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
// iOS < 8 Notifications
    _storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:

     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

if (launchOptions != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        /*[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary updateUI:NO];*/
    }
}

return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` isn't being called or printed either. How can this code be edited to print the device token in the NSLog?

Comment: You'll need to start using compiler directives [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290547/checking-ios-version-through-preprocessor), although, if you're now targeting iOS9+, then you no longer need code that supports iOS8

Comment: Does your provisioning profile have the remote notification capability enabled?

Comment: In Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, after clicking profiles and viewing the Provisioning profile that was just generated and downloaded, it lists Push Notifications in one of the enabled capabilities.

Comment: I noticed that the NSLog stopped printing the device token after removing an invalid provisioning profile that the project used to use. I have been trying to migrate to the new APNs Provider API and didn't see a mention of provisioning profiles in Apple's Documentation for `User Notifications`. After asking a question, I was given verification that Provisioning Profiles are still required to build.

Comment: There are currently 2 certificates that are associated with the Apple Developer account that I use: Development which is named after me and my MacBook, and Apple Push Services which is tied to the App ID that was created to enable push notifications. When making the new Provisioning Profile, only the Development certificate is available for selection on the `Select Certificates` step in creating a new provisioning profile.