# Xcode + Swift - Only have certain elements if device is using iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, swift, compatibility

I am making a game, and I didnt realise that I set the targeted device as iOS 8. I went to change it to iOS 7 so that it is compatible with more devices. However, as tested on iOS 7, I realised that the UIVisualEffectView does not work. Is there anyway I can have the UIVisualEffectView to only appear when the running device has iOS 8 and not iOS 7?

Comment: Read the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the docs. It covers this. Oh wait, that really only covers Objective-C.

Comment: The interoperability document discusses how to check for optional/new functionality.

Comment: How do you create the `UIVisualEffectView`?  If it's in code, show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `UIVisualEffectView` being available like this:

```
if (NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil) {
    NSLog("UIViewVisualEffectView is available");
    // Use UIVisualEffectView
} else {
    NSLog("UIViewVisualEffectView is not available");
    // Do something else
}
```

This approach is nice because the code documents why the `if` statement is being used, and you don't have to remember the OS version when a class was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version). You can get the current iOS version using one of the macros in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/2770572), then decide which classes to use. For example:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
    // Use UIVisualEffectViewClass
} else {
    // Use another class
}
```

If you're using swift, ignore the macro part, and just use the code.