# Can I update my iphone application for iOS7 only?

Tags: iphone, ios7, app-store-connect

I have developed application for iphone4/5 with iOS 7 support. Recently I found issue in that and wanted to update application only for iOS7.

Does Apple allow me to update application for iOS 7 only? Do i have to give support for iOS 8 right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit with Xcode 5.1.1, you'll compile with iOS 7's SDK (and your app will behave as it behaves currently).

If you submit with Xcode 6.0, you'll compile with iOS 8's SDK (and you'll have to update your app due to new API and possible bugs).

Comment: So what i understand is that if i wanted to update application for iOS 7 only then i will have to compile is with XCode 5.1.1. Apple allows this right?

Comment: Yes, Apple still allows it, probably for a month or so. If you compile with Xcode 5.1.1, your app will behave exactly as it currently does under iOS 7 and iOS 8. The update will be available to iOS 7 AND iOS 8 users, but as long as you compile with Xcode 7.1.1, no new bugs will appear.

Answer (score 1):

use Xcode 5.1.1 if you want to fix issues only for iOS7 for time been and submit the app..but users might face issues if they are using iOS8 on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, I believe you should check in code for the user's iOS version and then update based on that.
See [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version) how to do that.