# I'm currently checking if UIAlertController exists to determine what OS version is being used. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, swift, xcode6

I have a delete button on a cell and it was crashing my app in iOS7 but not in iOS8. I later found out the crash was caused by by how deep down I was digging into my view hierarchy.

To make things clearer here is the code that solved the issue:

```
func didTapDeleteButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var cell: HoursOfOperationTableViewCell!
        if let gotModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") {
            println("UIAlertController can be instantiated")
            //make and use a UIAlertController
            cell = sender.superview?.superview? as HoursOfOperationTableViewCell
        }
        else {       
            println("UIAlertController can NOT be instantiated")
            cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview? as HoursOfOperationTableViewCell
        }
```

As you can see I have to go further down into my view hierarchy to get to my custom cell view in iOS 7.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of checking the iOS version?

If I don't check then my app crashes in iOS7 if I leave the code like this:

```
cell = sender.superview?.superview? as HoursOfOperationTableViewCell
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're doing it right. It's better to check for existence of the class, than for the OS version. Maybe the class name will change, maybe it will be deprecated/removed in iOS 12, etc.

Comment: I take it none of the solutions are suitable? Could you clarify why?

Comment: @DanielGalasko I've put this part of my project on hold but will get back to it soon and try out these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a class is loaded in the current runtime, you could call the following:

```
var classExistsAndIsSafeToUse = countElements(NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(UIAlertController))) > 0
```

You should always check for the existence of a particular class over checking the iOS version.

That being said, for checking the iOS version, below is an excerpt from my solution on [just that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version/26235067#26235067)

> New in iOS 8 is `NSProcessInfo` that integrates greatly with Swift and
>   allows for better semantic versioning checks. Thanks to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/)
>   we can see a clean and canonical source from where the OS version can
>   be derived.
>
> > For minimum deployment targets of **iOS 8.0** or above, use `NSProcessInfo`
> >     `operatingSystemVersion` or `isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion`.
>
> This would yield the following:
>
> ```
> let minimumVersion = NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 3, minorVersion: 1, patchVersion: 3)
> if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(minimumVersion) {
>     //do some fun stuff
> }
> ```
>
> > For minimum deployment targets of **iOS 7.1** or below, use compare with
> >     `NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch` on `UIDevice systemVersion`.
>
> This would yield:
>
> ```
> let minimumVersionString = "3.1.3"
> let versionComparison: NSComparisonResult = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(minimumVersionString,
> ```
>
> options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch)
>       if  versionComparison == .OrderedDescending {
>           //do some fun stuff
>       }

**EDIT**

as a side note, if you see something like this:

```
cell = sender.superview?.superview? as HoursOfOperationTableViewCell
```

your code has begun to exhibit whats known as code smell, you should consider implementing your view logic inside of your view, the controllers should not have a deep knowledge into the view hierarchy. Remember, the goal is on writing easy to change code. Consider implementing abstraction, delegation and singular responsibility principled design.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`. This returns an `NSString` so you will need to convert to a float if you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `NSFoundationVersionNumber`. Declare the following constants in a file where you keep global constants.

```
let iOS7 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
let iOS8 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
```

And check for the version like this.

```
if iOS8 {
    // Use iOS 8 APIs
} else {
    // Fallback for older iOS versions
}
```