# Why is this code updating location twice every time?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code, it all works fine but each time I hit the "Get My Location" button it updates the location twice, I cannot find the reason why, any idea's? I have removed much code from below this and it still does it so I know it's in this part somewhere. Thanks.

.h file:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LatitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LongitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *GPSAccuracyLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *AltitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *VerticalAccuracyLabel;

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;
@end

@interface MyLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error); UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"Location updated: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _LatitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _GPSAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
    _AltitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.altitude];
    _VerticalAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.verticalAccuracy];
}
```

Console output each time I press the button:

```
2014-11-22 23:49:37.539 MyLocationDemo[914:60b] Location updated: <+10.16863927,+124.75859298> +/- 10.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22/11/14 11:49:37 pm Philippine Standard Time

2014-11-22 23:49:37.545 MyLocationDemo[914:60b] Location updated: <+10.16863927,+124.75859298> +/- 10.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22/11/14 11:49:37 pm Philippine Standard Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at Apple's documentations, I've noticed that the delegate method you are using, `- locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated since iOS 6.
Instead, you should use `- locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

Try replacing your code with the code below and see if it make any difference:

EDIT- I've edit the code below to handle the double-call you get.
From your post above I see they are almost simultaneously, So basically we'll check if at least 1 seconds has passed since last call.
There are probably better ways to do it, but that was just at the top of my head...
Haven't checked it in Xcode, but, if I haven't made a typo or something, it should work.

```
// ViewController.m  
@interface ViewController ()  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastUpdateTime;  // Create a property  
@end                                                   // to hold current time  

- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];  // In viewDidLoad, 'initialize' it  
                                          // to get the current time  
}  

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations  
{  
    NSTimeInterval passedTime = -[self.lastUpdateTime timeIntervalSinceNow];  
    // Here we are checking how much seconds have passed since our lastUpdateTime  
    // Since lastUpdateTime is in the past, the result will be negative, therefore  
    // the minus sign, so we'll get a positive number  

    if(passedTime < 1) {  
        return;  
    }  // Now we check if less than one second have passed. If so, the whole method  
       // will return. If not, it will just continue executing

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];  
    self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];  // Don't forget to update the lastUpdateTime  
                                          // To hold the new update time

    if (currentLocation != nil) {  
        NSLog(@"Location updated: %@", currentLocation);
        _LatitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];  
        _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];  
        _GPSAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];  
        _AltitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.altitude];  
        _VerticalAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.verticalAccuracy];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I spoke too soon, I re-did the complete app (also changed to - locationManager:didUpdateLocations: but still it updates twice! I see it in the output console and the File Saved alert pops up twice. No idea why!

Comment: I notice though when using simulator I get "Location updated" in console plus an error "An Error occurred" (Cocoa error 4.) I guess the error is because it cannot fine var/mobile/Documents" folder which I understand but this tells me it's giving me two updates, one for location update and another update when it saves the file!

Comment: I'll edit my code to handle the double-call. I'm not sure you can use location services in the simulator, which I'm guessing is the cause of both errors.

Comment: I'm so glad to see you again, I am checking on device & simulator, I can get it working in simulator but I get expected error for the file saving part. I stripped code to bare minimum you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087329/why-does-this-location-code-updates-twice

Comment: My edit doesn't really answer the question why does it gets called multiple times. It just handles it so cases of double calls will be ignored.

Comment: It works!!! I'm so happy. If I could be so bold, can I ask you another question? When I press the button all location data appears on screen like it should, but if I then close the app and re-open it all the data is still there from last time. How can I make it so each time I open the app all data is from previous update is gone? Thanks pal.

Comment: Glad to hear it works mate. As for your question, this is probably because you don't close the app, you just press the home button, which causes the app to move to background. Have a look at `UIApplicationDelegate` reference, which can be found here (or in Xcode's documentations) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

@AMI289, your idea worked, no more double call.

I post the final code here in case it helps others, I just added back the `locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`.

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastUpdateTime; // create a property to hold current time.
@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];  // In viewDidLoad, 'initialize' it to get the current time
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSTimeInterval passedTime = -[self.lastUpdateTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
// Here we are checking how much seconds have passed since our lastUpdateTime
// Since lastUpdateTime is in the past, the result will be negative, therefore
// the minus sign, so we'll get a positive number

if(passedTime < 1) {
    return;
}  // Now we check if less than one second have passed. If so, the whole method
// will return. If not, it will just continue executing

CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];  // Don't forget to update the lastUpdateTime
// To hold the new update time

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Location updated: %@", currentLocation);
    _LatutideLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _GPSAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
    _AltitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.altitude];
    _VerticalAccuracyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.verticalAccuracy];
}
// Stop Location Manager
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

Comment: Oh I see, I added back the locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; Will test now pal.