# Creating an app with deployment target of iOS 7.1 and optional iOS 8-only features

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm creating an app that works with CloudKit framework (iOS 8-only) but still want to keep compatibility with iOS 7.1, with no CloudKit functionality, of course. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3) recommends checking for optional classes like this:

```
if ([CKRecordID class]) {
    // iOS 8 code
} else {
    // iOS 7 code
}
```

This works. On the other hand, if I write

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) CKRecordID *recordID;
@end
```

anywhere in the code, the app will crash on iOS 7 when loading the `Foo` class. How can I define properties with those optional classes?

Comment: u can check device system version is >8.0 or not and u can go for it....!
This is not the one you want but it is just alternative..!

Comment: use if condition like this if([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0f]){ //ios 8 code } else { //ios 7 or lower version code}

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/target-conditionals-and-availability/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the forward declaration

```
@class CKRecordID;
```

but you will need runtime checks for the iOS version, such as

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion]
```

Other solutions for detecting the iOS version are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337804/1864294) or [here](http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/check-ios-version-and-write-conditional-code/).

But how about two different builds for different iOS versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your property `recordId` of type id or `NSObject`.

And when you need to access this property (after checking that your runtime is iOS8+), you cast it to `CKRecordID` class.