# How to check iOS version, in a C file?

Tags: ios, c

I have some C files that are dependent on iOS 9, (using new features from the accelerate framework) and want to be able to check the current iOS version without using Objective-C.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version

Comment: Don't check the iOS version. Check for the availability of the API you wish to use.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, can you elaborate?  If I want to use vDSP_biquadm_SetTargetsDouble() what would that look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not check the version of iOS. The proper solution is to check if the desired API is available. In this case you wish to use the `vDSP_biquadm_SetTargetsDouble` function. As described in the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i), the proper way is this:

```
if (vDSP_biquadm_SetTargetsDouble != NULL) {
    // The vDSP_biquadm_SetTargetsDouble function exists, use it here
} else {
    // There is no vDSP_biquadm_SetTargetsDouble function. Do something else (or nothing)
}
```