# Xcode UI Testing: lldb error "only available on iOS 9.0 or newer"

Tags: ios, swift, lldb, xcode-ui-testing

#### Background

I have a fairly detailed (around 2000 lines of swift code) automation framework built with Xcode 7.3 and Swift for our iOS app.

Up till a recent point, I was able to use `lldb` to build my framework i.e

- insert breakpoint and run code up till that point
- use `po XCUIApplication().debugDescription` and `expr bla bla` to build the logic
- repeat

---

#### Problem

Pretty much all of a sudden, I now encounter the following error whenever running anything inside `lldb`'s console:

```
(lldb) po XCUIApplication()
error: <EXPR>:2:1: error: 'XCUIApplication' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer
XCUIApplication()
^
<EXPR>:2:1: note: add 'if #available' version check
XCUIApplication()
^
<EXPR>:2:1: note: add @available attribute to enclosing instance method
XCUIApplication()
^
<EXPR>:2:1: note: add @available attribute to enclosing extension
XCUIApplication()
^
<EXPR>:10:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
    var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

#### Notes

Googling and research has not gotten me anywhere significant. 
The one relevant thread I found was in the [fastlane project](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/2532#issuecomment-218371518). Unlike that comment, mine is a UI Test target. 
Also, the test target's "iOS Deployment Target" is set to iOS 9.2 (in case that helps).

- To the extent I remember, I haven't changed anything significantly in recent times.
- My device is (and has always been) iOS 9+.

What could be going wrong?

#### Update 20 May 2016

Some exploration based on the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37335950/682912

- The issue happens only on real devices. Simulators do not face this problem.
- On real device (iPhone 6S+, iOS 9.2.1), I did a full reset of Content and Settings. This did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you running on a device or simulator running below iOS 9?

Comment: Within the debugger, try some of the method calls here to verify the OS version: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)

Comment: @Oletha as mentioned, it's iOS 9+ (9.2.1). 
@bneely  `po NSProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion` returns `▿ NSOperatingSystemVersion
  - majorVersion : 9
  - minorVersion : 2
  - patchVersion : 1` i.e 9.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the debug agent installed on your device.  These are bound to the iOS version, so it probably happened when you upgraded your device.  Anyway, please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

If I'm right about the problem, it should only happen when debugging to the device, not on the simulator. That might allow you a temporary workaround till the bug gets fixed.

Comment: "it should only happen when debugging to the device, not on the simulator." Let me try this out and update this.

Comment: Update: you are right! 
`(lldb) po XCUIApplication()
    t =    43.01s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.crunch.CrunchCastQA.iOS
Attributes: Application 0x7ffedce003c0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: 'Foo'
Element subtree:
`

Apart from filing a bug report, is there anything I can do? Will resetting content and settings help?

Comment: Update: resetting content and settings did not help.

Comment: Probably need more info before we can suggest a workaround.  Best to do that through the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your .xcconfig with your test target or any other means that may set your IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to lower than 9.0.
Since UITest is only available on iOS9.0 or later, change IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 9.0+ should fix the issue.