# Detect iOS version in xcode - Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have inherited some code in xcode (below) and am getting an `'Unexpected '@' in program'` error reported.

I have been able to figure out that this is likely to be due to the fact that the original code was written in xcode >9.0 while my version (due to hardware limitations) is xcode 8.2.1

From researching, I have determined that the issue is with this part of the code:

```
 if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
```

Which I need to change to

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
```

But if I do that, I then get the following error

```
Expected '(' after 'if'
```

The original piece of code is

```
if ([self.uploadProgress respondsToSelector:@selector(setResumingHandler:)]) {
    if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
        [self.uploadProgress setResumingHandler:^{
            __typeof__(weakTask) strongTask = weakTask;
            [strongTask resume];
        }];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

And this is what I have tried to change it to

```
if ([self.uploadProgress respondsToSelector:@selector(setResumingHandler:)]) {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        [self.uploadProgress setResumingHandler:^{
            __typeof__(weakTask) strongTask = weakTask;
            [strongTask resume];
        }];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That's because the one you are using is for Swift, not objective c. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version/44429397#44429397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

available(iOS 9.0, *) is used in swift for objective-c you can try this

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max)
```

OR

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >=  __IPHONE_10_0
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

    #endif
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the difference between swift/objective-c that I hadn't fully understood. Thanks.