# how to set the UIWebView starting offset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UIWebView` in which y origin I set the same as the `UINavigationBar` (both 0). I have a .95 alpha set on my `UINavigationBar`, the goal is so that when I scroll the `UIWebView` up I can sort of see the content of the `UIWebView` a bit. However the issue is that when I do this the content of the `UIWebView` starts from the top. How do I make it so that the content when initially start is below the `UINavigationBar` and not behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `webView.clipsToBounds = NO;`. That could work.
Also, since iOS5 you can find the UIScrollView within the webView and set a contentInset value.

See: [UIWebView under transparent UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431511/uiwebview-under-transparent-uinavigationbar/8114150#8114150)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If your navigation bar is translucent the web view will start behind the nav bar , if u make it translucent = NO then it starts right below , hep this might help